how can i make tiling with a dent in the gap?
I'm recreating colleage building in blender and i'm having trouble making material for metalic tiled wall like this.

(sorry for bad resolution)
I tried using brick texture node and displacement to make indent but all geometry was all just flat faces. It just looks like it has indent
I think it's because the material is applied to simple cube mesh. but i couldn't find appropriate ways to add more faces to mesh in this specific situation
Subdivision is inefficient because i only need more faces between gaps.
At this point, i also considered just using loop cut, bevel, extrude to manually make all faces and also manually applying metalic wall texture and mortar texture.
But it's so time-consuming selecting face one by one in edit mode. Because this metalic wall is all over the building like pillar and other side of exterior.
If material do it by itself, i can just play with simple square in UVediting for different part of building and it will be super efficient.
How can i solve this problem?

Does it need to be in geometry? Would a bump-map do?

Strongly consider whether it will be worth it to add the geometry.  This is one of those judgement calls between additional realism (in this case, probably negligible) and additional render time.  Also consider that when you destructively make these changes it's much harder to come back later and change to a smaller brick, for example.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that a wall with the appearance of an indent is the actual goal.  Whether the indent is real or fake hardly matters; as long as it looks convincing enough you're the only one who will know.

Bump map also work great accept for corner of pillar. But yeah it doesn't worth more effort and render time. Thank you for your advise

But still I wish I could know if making indent is possible
